# Accessing xml attributes from a child node

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

In my XML file I have a node which is there per layer node like so:

```
<layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="30" height="30">
  <data>
   <tile gid="69"/>
   <tile gid="69"/>
```

and

```
<layer name="Collsions" width="30" height="30">
  <data>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
   <tile gid="0"/>
```

Now if I use the following statement using xpath

```
xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "//tile/@gid";
```

I can get all the tile gids. My issue is I would like to retrieve tile gids for just the collisions layer.

Some pseudo:

```
//get to layer node
if(name == collision)
{
   get tile gids for this node list only
}
```

How do I do this?

I tried using the `currentNode->xmlChildrenNode` and it went down the nodes, but for some reason it returned "text" at one point? Is this due to whitespace?

I use this in the following code(expression changed to `xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/layer[@name=\"Collisions\"]/data/tile/@gid";`

```
xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/layer[@name=\"Collisions\"]/data/tile/@gid";//"//tile/@gid";
xmlNodeSetPtr nodeset;
xmlXPathObjectPtr result;
int i;
xmlChar *keyword;
int numCollisionTiles = 0;

result = getnodeset (doc, xpath);
if (result) 
{
    nodeset = result->nodesetval;
    for (i=0; i < nodeset->nodeNr; i++) 
    {
        keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);

        int id = atoi(keyword);
        int index = i;
        if(id == 111)
        {
            numCollisionTiles += 1;
            index -= 899;
            printf("tile id : %d for index: %d\n", id, index);
        }

        xmlFree(keyword);
    }
    xmlXPathFreeObject (result);
}
printf("number of collision tiles : %d\n", numCollisionTiles);
```

}

This code works when I use the following `xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "//tile/@gid"`

Could the following

```
keyword = xmlNodeListGetString(doc, nodeset->nodeTab[i]->xmlChildrenNode, 1);
```

be causing `xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/layer[@name=\"Collisions\"]/data/tile/@gid";` to find nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`/layer[@name="Collisions"]/data/title/@gid`

or

`//tile[../../@name="Collisions"]/@gid`

Comment: There is an issue with the " " because the regex has to be in " like so "/layer[@name="Collisions"]/data/title/@gid"

Comment: yeah, you have to escape the double quotes like so: `xmlChar *xpath = (xmlChar*) "/layer[@name=\"Collisions\"]/data/title/@gid";` (though that depends on the programming language you are using, I'm assuming it's C).

Comment: Yeah its C. Thanks, I thought the escaping could effect the expression. None of the above seem to work though. :( Im not sure why, or how to fix it. Unless it is because of my other code. I will update my question with the code in 1 sec. thanks

Comment: No worries. I solved it by adding a / infront of /layer[@name="Collisions"]/data/title/@gid. and I had Collsions instead of Collisions in my xml source. pfff :/